# Intelli J IDEA Ultimate PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin project run is not working because Environment-Variables

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea, environment-variables, phonegap

I have got Intelli J IDEA Ultimate, Node.js and PhoneGap/Cordova plugins are Installed.

I created a project with PhoneGap/Cordova plugin then I tried to run project with Intelli J IDEA but that gives this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/phonegap run --emulator android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run --emulator android ' ...
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Detected 'adb' command at /usr/bin but no 'platform-tools' directory found near.
Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to SDK/platform-tools directory.
```

Comment: Also i'm using Elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Where do you set environment variables? Note that depending on the way setting them, variables may be not available to GUI applications that are not started from the terminal.